# How to make a framework to collect data from a website to be displayed in a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web-scraping

I have been looking at similar questions on this website and Im looking to try to get certain pieces of information from a .xml file on a website that I then duplicate for each individual lake. I am trying to make something that will be able to get the current water level for each of these lakes. I found this tool that can generate .xml of the data but I dont know how to have flutter read that and update it every so often if that makes sense.

https://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/DV-Test-Tool.html

I was testing this site using Neosho River with the Site number: 07179500. This gives me the following url that seems to contain relevant updated information such as the current discharge rate.

https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/dv/?format=waterml,2.0&sites=07179500&siteStatus=all

How can I have it pull information like this and then re-check every x time to update the current water level etc? I was looking at json? but most guides I found use a file you upload and not a website.

Additionally, there are several other links that may be helpful and might have a better type of data
https://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/

https://waterservices.usgs.gov/rest/DV-Service.html

https://help.waterdata.usgs.gov/faq/automated-retrievals

https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/dvstat?&site_no=07179500&agency_cd=USGS&por_07179500_55652=92891,00060,55652,1938-10-01,2021-11-21&stat_cds=mean_va&referred_module=sw&format=html_table

https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nc/nwis/uv?cb_00062=on&format=html&site_no=02098197&period=&begin_date=2022-02-28&end_date=2022-03-01

https://www.swt-wc.usace.army.mil/

If flutter can not do this is there something else I can use to work with flutter?